# Hsqldb doesn't get populated with data

Tags: java, spring, orm, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I want to insert sql data when I run this datasource configuration but I can't get the data in my test class. It works if I create the data first inside the test class and getting it though.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("se.system.repository")
public class DBConfig{

@Bean(name = "hsqldb")
public DataSource InMemoryDataSource() {

    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase database = builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("classpath:se/system/sql/create-db.sql")
            .setName("database")
            .build();

    return database;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}

@Bean 
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
    adapter.setShowSql(false);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true); 
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    factory.setDataSource(InMemoryDataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("se.system.model");
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.setSqlScriptEncoding("UTF-8");
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("se/system/sql/insert-data.sql"));
    return populator;
}

@Bean
public InitializingBean populatorExecutor() {
    return () -> DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator(), InMemoryDataSource());
}
```

Inside a testclass:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws ServiceException {

    try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()) {

        context.scan("se.system");
        context.refresh();

        userService = context.getBean(UserService.class);


        System.out.println(userService.getUserById(1L));  

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring will look for **data.sql** as well as **data-${platform}.sql** files to run. It uses Spring JDBC to do this.

Try renaming your sql file to data.sql and adapt your method accordingly:

```
populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("se/system/sql/data.sql"));
```

instead of

```
populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("se/system/sql/insert-data.sql"));
```

[http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html](http://database-initialization)

Comment: Now I get this error : "user lacks privilege or object not found: User" After I try to populate with a user, I'm guessing that the in memory db doesn't persist the data when I try to run the test